# JavaScript - What's the point of the condition in this if statement: if(document.getElementById)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand some code and I don't understand the point of the mentioned condition in the if statement. Does the if statement consider the value of that condition true everytime `document.getElementById` is run in the code?

```
if(document.getElementById) {
    window.alert = function(txt) {
        createCustomAlert(txt);
    }
}
```

And isn't `getElementById` a method with a required string parameter?

Comment: Depends on what `createCustomAlert` does. But `getElementById` is supported by virtually any browser, so it's probably useless (or just an error) anyway.

Comment: Now that I think of it, it could be to check *whether* it's running inside a browser.

Comment: "_And isn't getElementById a method with a required string parameter?_" Yes, it is, but in the condition the author is not calling the method, they only refer to it.

Answer (score 2):

Probably It is checking if the code is running in a browser or in a console (like node).

If it is running in a browser it changes the `alert` method to use his custom alert.

**Update:**  As Jared Smith noted, `document` should be defined before doing the `if` statement.

Comment: Might be worth noting that it's a *bad* check for whether you're running in a browser: unless you define `document` in node you'll get a ReferenceError instead of false. Then there's Workers...

Comment: That's true, now  I'm more confused about that code

Comment: A better check for this particular use would be `if (typeof alert === 'function' && alert !== myCustomAlert) alert = myCustomAlert;`

Answer (score 0):

It actually checks if the code is running in the browser or not.

If it returns true, which could be true in your case, then it replaces alert method to use this custom `createCustomAlert` method.